# How to get jquery POST request from indirect Page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been working on Like and Unlike feature with jQuery, AJAX and PHP. I am getting jQuery post request from indirect page. For example I have 2 PHP pages, `viewProfile.php` and `LikeMail.php`. `LikeMail.php` is being called by AJAX function in `viewProfile.php`.

Here is Section of viewProfile.php page's description

```
                             -----------------
                            |   Like/Unlike   |
                             -----------------
```

Here is button which actually comes from `LikeMail.php` by this AJAX function:

```
function like()
{
    var req  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()

    {
        if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('like1').innerHTML=req.responseText;

        }
    }
    req.open('POST','LikeMail.php','true');
    req.send();
}
setInterval(function(){like()},1000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="like1"></div>
```

Output is being shown here in this `div`. *Button above may be `Like` or `Unlike` depends on the condition in `LikeMail.php` which will be described below in `LikeMail.php` description section.*

When one of them (buttons) `Like` or `Unlike` is clicked. It then calls respective jQuery click function which sends post request to `LikeMail.php`.I have mentioned `Indirect` page in title because `Like` or `Unlike` buttons actually exists in `LikeMail.php` page. But due to AJAX call these buttons are being shown in `viewProfile.php` page. So I then send post requests through `viewProfile.php` to actual page `LikeMail.php`
**It is jQuery post for `Unlike` button**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Unlike').unbind().click(function(){
        $.post("LikeMail.php",
            {Unlike: this.id},
            function(data){
                $('#response').html(data);
            }

        );

    });

});
```

**It is jQuery post or `Like` button**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Like').unbind().click(function(){
        $.post("LikeMail.php",
            {Like: this.id},
        function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);
        }
        );

    });

});
```

End of description section of `viewProfile.php` page

---

**Here is Section of LikeMail.php page's description**

`Like` or `Unlike` button is shown in `viewProfile.php` page depends upon this code:

```
$check_for_likes = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM liked WHERE user1='$user1' AND user2='$user2'");
                $numrows_likes = mysqli_num_rows($check_for_likes);
                if (false == $numrows_likes) {
                    echo mysqli_error($conn);
                }

                if ($numrows_likes >= 1) {
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="Unlike" value="Unlike" id="Unlike" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">';

                }

                elseif ($numrows_likes == 0) {
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="Like" value="Like" id="Like" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">';
                }
```

Button depends upon these two above conditions.

Now when `Like` button is clicked, post request from `viewProfile.php` comes here.

```
if(isset($_POST['Like']))   //When Like button in viewProfile.php is clicked then this peace of code inside if condition should run and insert some record in database
            {
                $total_likes = $total_likes+1;
                $like = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user SET user_Likes = '$total_likes' WHERE user_id = '$user2'");
                $user_likes = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO liked (user1,user2) VALUES ('$user1','$user2')");
                $query3 = "INSERT INTO notification (user1, user2, alert, notificationType) VALUE ('$user1','$user2','unchecked','like')";
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $query3)) {
                    echo "Like";
                } else {
                    echo mysqli_error($conn);
                }

            }
```

Similarly when `Unlike` button is clicked. This peace of code should run.

```
if(isset($_POST['Unlike'])) //This is the condition for Unlike button. It should delete record from databse
            {
                $total_likes = $total_likes-2;
                $like = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user SET user_Likes='$total_likes' WHERE user_id='$user2'");
                $remove_user = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM liked WHERE user1='$user1' AND user2='$user2'");
                $query3 = "DELETE FROM notification WHERE user1='$user1' AND user2='$user2' AND notificationType='like'";

                $check = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
                if ($check) {
                    echo "Unlike";
                } else {
                    echo mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            }
```

Problem:

Main problem is that jQuery post request is not being sent from `viewProfile.php` to `LikeMail.php`. Is there any way to send jQuery post request from indirect page?

Comment: Did you check the network tab of your browser's console?

Comment: Its blank. Nothing there

Comment: Go to the sources tab and add a breakpoint to the button click function. Try clicking and see if it enters there.

Comment: What do you mean breakpoint here

Comment: Oh you haven't learned how to debug yet. Take a look at [this link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints), debugging is extremely helpful.

Comment: OK sure.. I have a question here that, Is it possible to send post request from other page?

Comment: Yes you can, that's how it's done. Your `$.post` seems ok, there might be something else, probably on the click event.

Comment: I have just done it but nothing happens there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121369/discussion-between-phiter-fernandes-and-zain-farooq).